# Lubuntu 14.04 desktop lockscreen resolution

Tags: lock-screen

Lubuntu 14.04 desktop - my lockscreen defaults away from my set resolution on main screen to the default of 1920x1080 - how can I mend this to match main screen 1280x960?

thanks

Comment: Is this not possible? - just looking 4some pointers how to do it.  Would seem to me it should be the same resolution but it isn't.

Comment: Please check the /etc/X11/xorg.conf . look for "preferredmode". What is the value of this?

Comment: Thanks - looking for xorg.conf file under /etc/X11 but seems it's not there.